# MySQL multi-valued index for Spring app with Hibernate ORM cause error on initialization

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have been trying to utilize the [multi-valued index type on MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) on my Spring Boot app. I found out that the index produced from this method will have null column_name as shown below.

This index definition affects the hibernate-core library used during initialization which requires the index column identifier, resulting in an error thrown in `toMetaDataObjectName()` method call. The index itself is created manually using the native query, not auto-generated.

Is there a workaround to make the app initialization successful?

```
mysql> alter table editor_selection add index warehouses_idx( (CAST(warehouses->'$' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY)) );

mysql> show index from editor_selection;
+------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name                     | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression                                                        |
+------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| editor_selection |          0 | PRIMARY                      |            1 | id            | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL                                                              |
| editor_selection |          0 | UK_n7qyx3nm871legvu8y9idmf68 |            1 | uuid          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL                                                              |
| editor_selection |          0 | UK_can8tqofxj7e9kmj7d41w95hw |            1 | slug          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL                                                              |
| editor_selection |          1 | display_score_idx            |            1 | display_score | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL                                                              |
| editor_selection |          1 | section_name_idx             |            1 | section_name  | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL                                                              |
| editor_selection |          1 | warehouses_idx               |            1 | NULL          | A         |           0 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | cast(json_extract(`warehouses`,_utf8mb4\'$\') as char(255) array) |
+------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null was passed as an object name
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.sayurbox.catalog.Catalog.main(Catalog.java:22)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null was passed as an object name
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1795)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null was passed as an object name
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl.toMetaDataObjectName(NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getColumn(TableInformationImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getIndexes(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.indexes(TableInformationImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getIndex(TableInformationImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.findMatchingIndex(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyIndexes(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Solution is given here "https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-can-i-make-hibernate-ignore-my-custom-index/6149/13"

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be on this line

> mysql> alter table editor_selection add index warehouses_idx( (CAST(warehouses->'$' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY)) );

Try changing it to `AS CHAR ARRAY` and leave me a comment if it works or not.

Comment: The index cannot be created with that command. The error is `Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'CAST-ing data to array of char/binary BLOBs'`. Tried on both the MySQL version 8.0.17 and 8.0.27.